# Highlight rows with identical data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, highlighting

I have a number of rows within a large spreadsheet that have some identical rows  I would like those rows highlighted but only if every cell on the row matches, if random cells from different rows match, but not every cell on the row, the cell / row should be ignored.

[image: Example of what I would like]

So here you can see the desired effect Rows 191 and 192 are identical and have been highlighted. However even though the data in cells B190-B193 are the same, as is the data in cell N191-N193. The data in Cells that do not full match the other cells in their row have not been highlighted.

Using conditional formatting and other attempts mark any duplicate field and not ones where the entire row is identical.

Would appreciate any help, totally stuck!

Comment: If you're able to mark duplicates on a single field using conditional formatting, would it be satisfactory to concatenate all of the column data at the end of each row in a new column, then to a conditional format on that new column?

Comment: @dangowans If A1 is 1 and A2 is 11 and B1 is 11 and B2 is 1.  wouldn't the concatenations columns be be equal but the rows are actually different?

Comment: @ForwardEd True.  A unique delimiter between the values would fix that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks quite hideous but works:

[image]

Steps:

- Select `A1:D4` in my example:
- Apply new conditional formatting rule through formula:

  ```
  =COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA($A:$A)),$A1,INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA($B:$B)),$B1,INDIRECT("C1:C"&COUNTA($C:$C)),$C1,INDIRECT("D1:D"&COUNTA($D:$D)),$D1)>1
  ```
- Apply condidional formatting and press OK

---

Why not just `COUNTIFS` with full column ranges instead of the volatile `INDIRECT` ranges? Because this is going to be CPU heavy I would opt for a longer formula isntead of one that will constantly check the entire column (for who knows how many columns you want to implement).

Can't `INDIRECT` hurt? Not per se, since conditional formatting is volatile on it's own. Therefor I would go with a quick `COUNTA` on the range instead. And possibly even throwing in multiple `MATCH` function to get the last used row is faster.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)),$A1,INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)),$B1,INDIRECT("C1:C"&MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)),$C1,INDIRECT("D1:D"&MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A)),$D1)>1
```

It didn't become pretty but at least it got faster :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use conditional formatting with `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A=$A1),--($B:$B=$B1),--($C:$C=$C1),--($D:$D=$D1))>1
```

Comment: Would `COUNTIFS(...) > 1` be more efficient calculation-wise?

Comment: It might very well be. I have a hunch that there must be a more efficient way of doing this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I tend to get a little shakey when I see SUMPRODUCT with full column cell references.

Comment: Technically you could shorten it up by eliminating the "--" and replacing the "," with "*". but it will still do the same thing in the end.